# Can't log in to new Azure B2C directory

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started) to get a B2C AD up and running

1. Create the B2C directory in the old portal (http://manage.windowsazure.com) ensuring "This is a B2C Directory" is checked.
2. Register an application in the new portal (http://portal.azure.com) under the B2C blade
3. Create the sign in policy.

When I try and test the sign in policy with the "Run now" and try and log in with my local account (the same one which has created the B2C AD -- the global administrator for this new AD) all I am met with is "We don't recognize this user ID or password".

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this issue too. If you want to manage the users for the Azure B2C tenant, you can login the classic Azure Portal from [here](https://manage.windowsazure.com). However, currently there are a couple of known issues with user management (the Users tab) on the Azure classic portal:

[image]

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations) about the Azure Active Directory B2C: Limitations and restrictions.

And if you want Azure AD to enable to login with the default global admin account, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/).